# User belongs to different groups when logging in via control alt F1 than via ssh or su, including su -

Tags: linux, user-accounts, slackware

Made a guest account for a friend to access my machine and restricted him to a very small set of permissions.
That seems to work as expected using ssh, when running `id` and `groups`the correct groups are being shown, both invoked as root and as a user.
`su` ing also works as expected, guest group is the only one he belongs to.

All of that works when I ssh into my machine from the same machine, as well.

However, if I log in using a virtual terminal on that same machine with his account, and run `id` then he's in audio, cdrom, scanner, floppy and all that.

Distribution is Slackware 13.37 (updated to current), if it helps.

Comment: _How_ did you restrict him in this way?

Comment: @DanielAndersson I simply only made him a member of the 'guest' group and nothing else. I have yet to learn how to jail a user in his home properly, I don't mind him exploring the filesystem, but I have some disks mounted in media I don't want anyone snooping around in. So I put the requirement of being a part of the disk group to access those, which my friend does not belong to, and while the supplementary console groups don't include the disk one, they contain the audio one, and with that he would have been able to change my alsamixer settings, but that is sorted out now.

Comment: @DanielAndersson Not that he 'really' would have been able to change my audio settings since it only applies to VT login at my physical computer, but at time of posting this question I had no idea about that, obviously, hehe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the file that causes it.

```
/etc/login.defs
```

Line:

```
CONSOLE_GROUPS         floppy:audio:cdrom:video:scanner
```

Paraphrasing the comments regarding this setting:

The supplementary groups specified are only added to the user when logging into a shell with /bin/login, not when using a login manager such as kdm.

This explains the behavior since the VTs accessed with control alt F1 to F6 operate this way.

The comments also advise to disable supplementary console groups and add the users who need hardware access to the respective groups with `adduser`, `useradd` or editing `/etc/group/` directly.